# How to choose radiobutton in popup

Tags: popup, radio-button

In my application , I have to choose radio button value (yes or no) after I click on some button in the popup. when I click on the button , user will be navigated to home page of the application, where the user will be displayed with some message in the popup with yes or no value.I have tried the below code " WebElement radioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("notifyConfirm"));
            radioBtn.click(); "..but since the user is navigate from the child page to parent page, I am not able to click on the value in the popup using id....when I execute the script I am getting below error...**."Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with**

Comment: Er....there isn't any code posted. :-)

Comment: Well i didnt understand your question . But as far as i got your question, you should try trigger from jQuery . http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: here is the code, this was there in the original post but not highlighted " WebElement radioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("notifyConfirm")); radioBtn.click(); "